# How to align contents to center inside a nested component scenario in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have a nested component scenario where I set all the contents to be aligned to the center in `Root` Component. But when I try to use `Body` component inside `Layout` component, that `div` aligns to the left of the screen instead of center.

How do I make `Body` component elements to be aligned in the center?

I created a working example using [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chilupa/pen/YzKqJRw). You can see the output here. Could anyone please review and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the gist of my code

**Root Component**

```
function Root() {
  return (
    <div className="Root">
      Root
      <Layout className="Layout" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Layout Component**

```
function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      Layout
      <Body />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Body Component**

```
function Body() {
  return (
    <div className="Body">
      <div className="FieldsStyle">
        <div className="Row">Type 1</div>
        <div className="Row">Type 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your codepen looks good. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `div` with the class `FieldsStyle` uses `display:flex;` you can simply add `justify-content: center;` to the class inside `CSS`.

```
.FieldsStyle {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-group: 1;
    justify-content: center;
}
```